# Keyboard hides edittext and spinner in expandable list view child view

Tags: keyboard, android-edittext, expandablelistview

I am working on ExpandableListView for the first time and facing a problem, I have an expandable list view with a single child in each group, the child view has an imageview, three textviews, one editText below the textviews, a spinner below edit text and two buttons after spinner.
My problem is that when i click on edittext, which is actually having the request focus already given in xml, the keyboard moves my childview upwards which is absolutely fine, so that i can enter values in editbox, after clicking on button below the spinner, keyboard comes down which is good, but on clicking the editbox for the second time, the keyboard covers the edit text, spinner and the buttons, and I am not able to enter values in the editbox.

I have tried adjustPan in manifest, not working for me, i have tried scrollTo() for expandable listview to scroll the list when i click edittext, still not working.

Any help is appreciated.